Why does dereferencing a String (not &String) work in Rust?
In the following code, in calculate_length function we are sending String not &String, yet dereferencing works. I expected to get error something:
type String cannot be dereferenced
But the code compiles and run without any error/warnings.
fn main() {
    let  x = String::from("hello world");
    let z = calculate_length(x);

    println!("{:}", z);
}

fn calculate_length(s: String) -> usize {
    (*s).len()
}

Playgorund Code here

Because String implements Deref

@Jmb Can you please elaborate? I am self-learning Rust and even ChatGPT has some misunderstandings.
A data structure that implements Deref can be accessed both ways (*s) and s in this case. If so what was the reasoning behind doing so? Other data type such as i32 does not allow this.

This allows all the methods from str to be called directly on Strings without needing to call as_str first, e.g. it allows you to write s.len() even though len is a method of str, not String.

@Jmb What you said is true, except for the last part - len() is also defined on String.

First, String implements Deref, which means you can use the dereference operator * on it. However, you're partially correct that s can't be dereferenced. If you write let x = *s;, it won't compile because this would copy String's target type, str. And str can't be copied since it doesn't implement Copy due to being unsized.
But while *s can't be a value, it is a valid place expression, which means you can do some things to it, like assign to it, make it a reference &*s, or call methods on it.
Methods are very flexible and can add references and dereferences in order to find a suitable function with the specified name. In (*s).len(), the method adds & in order to call str::len, which would look like str::len(&*s) expanded out. The added reference keeps the str from needing to be copied. Then the dereference *s is expanded to become str::len(&*Deref::deref(&s)).
